# Parasitic inheritance and super methods

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Douglas Crockford defines his **Parasitic Inheritance** [here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html).

I'd like to use that inheritance pattern because it's simple and clear, but I'd like to call **super methods** without defining what Crockford calls the `uber` function, as I don't want to modify Object's prototype. How can I do?

I'd like to have some sort of nice syntax, without modifying Object... is this possible?

Comment: I don't know who voted you down, but it is not cool to vote down without commenting what is wrong with the question. So I contra vote you up.

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify Oject's prototype.  You should be able to create an `inherit` function that adds `uber`/`_super` without worrying about the built-in prototype.  It shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: that adds uber/_super to what, sorry?

Comment: @cdarwin - ... adds uber to the prototype of your constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

In his example, this:

```
function ZParenizor2(value) {
    var that = new Parenizor(value);
    that.toString = function () {
        if (this.getValue()) {
            return this.uber('toString');
        }
        return "-0-"
    };
    return that;
}
```

Would become this:

```
function ZParenizor2(value) {
    var that = new Parenizor(value);
    that.toString = function () {
        if (this.getValue()) {
            return Parenizor.prototype.toString.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        return "-0-"
    };
    return that;
}
```

-- edit --

On the other hand, you could also simply define a new class named, say, BaseObject, define all the basic extended methods on it (like 'uber', for example) and then base your object hierarchy on that.

Comment: I update my question: I'd like to have a nice sintax without modifying Object prototype. Am I asking too much?

Comment: @cdarwin: `Am I asking too much?` Maybe not. But you are surely asking the wrong thing. In Crockford's words (in the very page you linked): `I have been writing JavaScript for 8 years now, and I have never once found need to use an uber function. The super idea is fairly important in the classical pattern, but it appears to be unnecessary in the prototypal and functional patterns. I now see my early attempts to support the classical model in JavaScript as a mistake.`